# How to add custon UI jquery & Fancybox script to WP

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a javascript that uses jquery objects to do a number of things

first it finds images that are in a table adding these to a Fancybox gallery. This gallery has the Helper buttons allowing the original image to be seen in it's full size.

Secondly it finds tables that are wider than the holding div and reduces the text font size so it fits. Adding a make bigger button so the table can be seen in all it's glory within a fancybox.

I'm new to Wordpress and am struggling to understand the following

1. Do i need to link to jquery.ui.js & css the way you do in a html document?
2. Where to put the code, Do i link it in the header.php or as a addition to the Fancybox plugin?
3. How do you make a Jquery object as this doesn't work

   ```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("table").each(function()
       // do stuff 
        alert ("hello Holly");
      )};
   ```
4. How do you add the Fancybox helper buttons?

   ```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".fancybox-button").fancybox({
           prevEffect      : 'none',
           nextEffect      : 'none',
           closeBtn        : false,
           helpers     : {
           buttons : {}
           }
   });
   ```

   });

Thanx for your help

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are not already loading the jQuery UI .js and .css files in your theme/plugin you can add them via the wp_enqueue_script function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script
2. No, add them via the enqueue scripts function.
3. You need to wrap any inline scripts in a jQuery No Conflict wrapper.

   `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

       // do stuff //
   });`

more on jQuery no conflict in WordPress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers

Comment: You can actually load the jQuery UI core .js without needing to reference an external file.  Example:
`function your_script_loader() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');            
}    
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_script_loader');`

Comment: Since posting this question i read that jquery.ui is part of the core WP & is within the include directories do i still need to link to it?

Comment: Yes, you would still need to enqueue it.  See `your_script_loader()` function above for the code to do this.

Comment: HI I've been struggling to get this to work all day and not got it to work I'm putting it within header.php just above </head> I've also tried <?php
function my_scripts_method() {
 wp_enqueue_script(
  'custom-script',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
  array('jquery')
 );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
  custom-script is  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $("table").each(function()
    // do stuff 
     alert ("hello Holly");
   )};
tried hard coding the link to custom-script.js & that didn't work either.

Comment: I did manage to load custom-script from within the  theams admin page and that worked but it didn't have the ui-resizable.js because jquery-ui-core isn't loaded  Any suggestions what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a link to your site that can be shared?  Or can you post your code from functions.php and custom_script.js in pastebin?

Comment: Not easily it's on an intranet at work & i'm at home!  I've duplicated what i did [here](http://pastebin.com/vFMaH8Lw) functions.php? is that where i should be putting the code & not header.php